# How to interpret coefficient if the independent variable has negative values?

Tags: regression, interpretation, regression-coefficients

I have a simple OLS regression:

Y=a+B*X+epsilon

X is the percentage change in house prices and has negative values (except in the 99th percentile).

If the sign of 'B" coefficient is positive, how should I interpret it?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to CV! Can you elaborate what exactly you're confused about? $\beta \cdot x$ works like any other multiplication: If both are positive, the term is positive; if one is negative, the term becomes negative; if both are negative, the term becomes positive. In other words, if the coefficient is positive, then $y$ is positively correlated to $x$: Movement of $x$ corresponds to movement of $y$ in the same direction.

Comment: Did you plot your data and regression line to see what is happening?

Comment: Thank you. I think I am confused about if the interpretation of B changes if the data points in  x is all negative numbers. My understanding fro your answer is that the answer is a "no".